# Images to video conversion on my website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to implement that, a user having some pictures, can make a video of that pictures on my **website** and use it or download the video [Similar to facebook Lookback].

Is there any API that provide such services or i need to write my own PHP code for that??

I'm using Codeigniter, PHP.

Comment: i googled it but, can't get stuff worth it. i am a PHP developer, with MVC experianced about a year.

Comment: You may need to use a flash based application for this, I don't think PHP would handle this.

Comment: @MarioSegura Flash will soon be retired & not supported by mobile devices. Try to look into FFMPEG

Comment: is there any API provider in which i can post my images and get Video [or video URL] in response?? if no then how can i integrate flash application for my purpose mentioned, or the name of Flash application i need for that

Comment: Yes, there's an API provider : you can use Stupeflix API to do server side video renderings, using After Effects templates or built-in effects. Find it at http://developer.stupeflix.com/documentation, with a lot of other tools to do image / video processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg` is the right solution for you. i suppose you will have to try manually with ffmpeg.... php video toolkit http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvideotoolkit/ in some parts to make it a bit easier...
another  `imagemagick`.

Comment: or even execute a background image processing software if you have administrative control on server.